# Program not breaking

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

Could anyone provide insight into why my program keeps terminating when I am trying to break?

Below is the prompt:
Write a function that returns a list of numbers, say make_list. make_list will not take any arguments. In the function body, construct an empty list and then prompt the user to enter a nonnegative number, -999 to quit. You will need a loop. If the user enters a number other than -999, add it to the list. Once the user enters -999, quit the loop and return the list. (Do not include -999 in the list.)

Write another function, say sum_list, that takes a list of numbers as an argument and returns the sum of the list of numbers. If the list is empty return 0. Do not use the built-in sum function. Use a loop.

You need to call both functions. First call the make_list function. Then use the returned list as the argument for the sum_list function. Print the result.

My solution:

```
def make_list():
    i=[]
    while(True):
        n=int(input("Enter a number (-999 to quit): "))
        if n==-999:
            break
        i+=[n]
    return i
def sum_list(i):
    if len(1)==0:
        return 0
    sum1=0
    for k in i:
        sum1+=k
    return sum1
i=make_list()
s=sum_list(i)
print("Sum :", s)
```

Comment: the normal way to add an item to a list is `i.append(n)`.

Comment: why don't you give `if n == -999: return i`

Comment: Is this correct? `if len(1)==0:` Did you want to give `if len(i) ==0`? I recommend that you give more meaningful variable names so you can troubleshoot and fix the issues. `if len(1)==0:` will give you an error

Comment: Similar to @JoeFerndz's comment; as written the program gives `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` due to that `len(1)`. If I fix it to `len(i)`, it seems to behave as intended?

Comment: I'm literally blind. Thank you all for replying, I now know I should give my variables better names.